# Fast search crawling issue

Tags: fast-search

In our scenario we are having three lists in which the content in the lists are placed in the FAST through indexing and we need to use FQL to get the content to other sources for publishing (In our case we need to use either custom sharepoint service appliaction which should be automated using a timer job to send mails to different users in different timezones getting the items from FAST which are indexed from lists)whenever a new item is added into list crawling should be done to that particular item only and it should be send immediately to the user through email using timer job) will this be possible??
Are there will be any issues in crawling list items individually when new item added??
Please help me ..thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you referring to whether or not the data would be picked up by an incremental crawl when new data is added?  You could probably send out a notification but changes are found in the incremental, when you run it against your content.  Remember though, even if the data is in a List in Sharepoint the Search Apps only look at the data as a content repository, the data is exposed as content not lists.

Comment: When incremental crawl is done it should Pick the particular data only when new data is added.but can the item which has been crawled be sent immediately when timer-job fires??Can it be useful to use custom sharepoint service applicaton which is autonated one for making timer job to run 24X7..?

Comment: @MichaelF Is it better to use windows serivce / custom sharepoint service application for being automated to send the emails and to grab the content from FAST using FQL??Will there be any issues using the sutom service application?

Comment: Never tried to send an email with the Incremental, we tried FAST when we originally implemented our SP install but could never get it to work right.  So we opted for the Search Server that came with SP.  Incremental will find any new content, or updates but it's usually done with the schedule in the Search Service App, no timer job needed.

Comment: If you want to be sure that you are getting the content out with FQL then use your timer job and have it set to run after your crawl, but leave time for the index to update.  Then you should be able to get any updated records.

Comment: In our case we are going to add new items every 10minutes and it should be done incremental call.So what happens when an incremental call is done to that particular item added to list??Can we send the items in different time zones as set by timer job.since you said that it needs time to update the index.will the crawl start from the new item or it considers the whole previous data too??

Comment: Incremental Crawls I believe look at the whole content but only reviews/indexes updates, how it's done I don't know since some of the Search internals I have not found information on.  You should be able to have notifications like you want, although you need to giver more detail on what you are doing ot be sure.  Right now some of your specifics are rather vague, but you should be able to do what you are asking.

Comment: @michaelF thanks for the info .its helpful to me alot..:-)